# ionic 5 button with text + icon, flush icon on the side

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Here's the button :

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-button class="m-0" (click)="calcVolume()" expand="full" color="primary">
    {{'discover_my_recommended_volume'|translate}}
    <ion-icon slot="end" name="chevron-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
  </ion-button>
</ion-footer>
```

How to flush the icon, in a button with text and icon, completely on the right ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

````
  <ion-button class="m-0" (click)="calcVolume()" expand="full" color="primary">
    {{'discover_my_recommended_volume'|translate}}
  </ion-button>
<ion-icon slot="end" class="ion-float-right" name="chevron-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
</ion-footer>```

Adding 'ion-float-right' class to the icon should do the trick
````